# Programmatic way to determine if code is running from unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have production code and test code. I want to know whether or not the production code is running from unit tests.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: You should take a step back and really think about why you think you need this. One of the points of unit tests is that you're checking a small part of the code **as if it were in production**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Java Stack Trace:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

This will return an array of [StackTraceElements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) which you can check. For instance, for your production code the last element should be the class with the Java main method. Whereas with a unit test you should end up with the class of a test runner.

For instance running JUnit in Eclipse leads to this last `StackTraceElement`

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need some way to tell, from within the production code, whether it has been invoked from unit tests or not.

I have in mind 2 possible approaches:

1. Assuming that the code runs in a single thread, use [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).
2. Use a [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (e.g. System.setProperty("testMode", "ON")).

Anyway, I agree with Jack Maney's comment. Reconsider this before adding dirt to your production code.